# Does the choice of "of/to" after "ascent" mean anything about the process?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

Taking a look at the Corpus of Contemporary American English, there seems to be an about equal number of `ascent of` versus `ascent to`. Examples from the corpus:

`[...]an expedition in honor of the 50th anniversary of the first American ascent of Everest.`

`The ascent to Mountain Lake Lodge is a slow, winding seven miles.`

I was wondering whether there is a sense or "process" when using the preposition `to`, meaning an ascent that is perhaps not completed, whereas `ascent of` would be preferred when referring to the actual conquest of a mountain.

Comment: The _ascent of_ Mt. Everest in your example is a completed act; the _ascent to_ Mountain Lake Lodge is a process, slow and winding.

Comment: Mount Lake Lodge apparently is at a hilltop, so the ascent **to** the lodge (ascent **of** the hill) is slow. HTH.

Answer (score 1):

No, choosing *of* or *to* doesn't relate to the process of ascent.

The ascent *of* X relates to the thing being scaled (e.g. X may be a mountain), while the ascent *to* Y relates to the destination (e.g. Y may be the peak of the mountain).

> **of** *preposition*
> 6.2 Followed by a noun expressing the object of the verb underlying the first noun.
> ‘payment of his debts’
> [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/of)
>
> **to** *preposition*
> 1Expressing motion in the direction of (a particular location)
> ‘my first visit to Africa’
> [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/to)